# choose the correct option ..? (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

let  $f = u +iv$ and $g = v +iu $ be  nonzero analytics  function on $|z| < 1$.then its  follows that

choose the correct option

a) $f ' = 0   $

b) $f$ is  conformal on $|z| < 1$

C) $f =cg$ for some real $c$

d) $ f$ is one -one

My attempts :  i can discard  option d) take $f(z) = z^2$ so it  is false

for  b) for  f  is conformal  $f' \neq  0$ as take $ f$ = $e^z$ so its contradicts

im confusing about option a) and option d)

pliz help me

any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Be clear: what do you mean by $\;f'\;$ ? Derivative with respect to $\;z\;$ , or maybe with respect to $\;\overline z\;$ ? Or perhaps something else?

Comment: sorry with its   respect  to z bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key fact is the relationship between $f$ and $g$; namely, the analytic function $-i f$ is given by

$$-if = v - iu = \overline{g}.$$

On the other hand, if $g$ and $\overline{g}$ are both analytic, then it should be easy to see that $g$ is actually constant (via the Cauchy-Riemann equations, perhaps, or by knowing things about $z \mapsto \overline{z}$). This tells you quite a bit about $u$ and $v$, of course.

---

Unfortunately, this means that your work so far is incorrect. For example, if $f(z) = z^2$, then $u = x^2 - y^2$ and $v = 2xy$. However, the corresponding $g$ is not analytic. Likewise for your answer to (b).

Comment: thanks u @T.Bongers